# Django caching an entire rendered HTML page for all website visitors

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

I have a particular view which takes over a minute to load for all users. The contents of the view aren't specific to the user viewing the rendered HTML it produces (it's a large schedule), but it's not possible (and highly inefficient, I imagine) to run that expensive operation every time someone visits the schedule page.

So what I want to do is cache the rendered contents of that entire page in my database or even a file in S3, perhaps. All the Django and caching documentation in general which I've seen talk about caching each unique visitor to the portion of the app you want to cache, but not for the site as a whole. I want to present the same cached view to everyone, always. I'm not even sure if caching is the right word, in this case.

The reason it's not a static page is because the contents do change a few times a day (approximately), but I have no problem connecting a post_save signal to the schedule such that it'll refresh the cached and full rendered HTML content.

This is my first time delving into caching, so maybe there's some fundamental flaw in my understanding. Would appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, almost all of Django's documentation talks about caching for all users, especially the [per-view cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache) which does precisely what you want. Caching per unique user is much more difficult.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting! But Daniel, what I'm still not getting is that these methods, they require one person to first trigger the view function right? So someone is going to have the user who suffers the long load time every time the cache expires, but then the response will be cached and speedily available for everyone going forward. Is that assumption correct? Thank you so much.

Comment: To avoid first user experiencing slowness, you can write a script to fire an HTTP request every now and then (or specifically after your content updates) so that the page gets into the cache. Regular cache warming stuff.